# Laravel - Using controller function for two different eloquent models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am currently developing an application for an indy movie production company. The way I have the workflow right now, the user begins by creating a new movie object by entering the movie title and synopsis. From there the user can then add more details such as price, run-time, full-screen/wide-screen, etc. The movie basic (title, synopsis) are in one database table, and the details are in another. I have set up a one-to-one relationship between the two eloquent models. I have also set up a MovieController that allows me to very easily do CRUD operations on the movie basic model, and when I am displaying the movie object to the user, I can display both the basics and details.

What I was wondering was there some way to use the already existent functions in the movie controller to do CRUD operations on the movie details without having to create new functions in the controller? Also is it possible to reuse the views I've created for each corresponding CRUD operation? In other words can I would like

`something.dev/cms/create`

In one instance to match to creating a new movie (title, synopsis) and in another instance to match to creating the movie detail (price, run-time, full-screen/widescreen) etc. Is this possible? I have provide the code for the two models below:

**Movie_basic.php**

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Movie_basic extends Model {

    protected $fillable = ['movie_title', 'movie_synopsis'];

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function details()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Movie_detail', 'movie_id');
    }

    public function personnel()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Movie_personnel', 'movie_id');
    }
}
```

**Model_detail.php**

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Movie_detail extends Model {

    protected $fillable = ['minutes', 'languages', 'viewer_discretion', 'screen_type', 'price'];

    protected $guarded = ['id', 'movie_id'];

    public function basics()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Movie_basic');
    }

}
```

Comment: If im reading it right basically you want to create a new _service_ and register it as a dependency for different controllers.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/container

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, this might be an answer. (Did not test the code.)

*Please note that, that code has been written to show you an example. You will probably want to edit it to make it work and act as you wanted. Maybe you want to use a repository or automate the model instance creating (I did not create new instances), and saving processes. You can use interfaces instead of your models etc...*

Here is the service to store the logic.

```
<?php
use Movie_basic; use Movie_detail;

Class MovieService {

    protected $movieBasic;
    protected $movieDetail;

    public function __construct(Movie_basic $movieBasic, Movie_detail $movieDetail) {

        $this->movieBasic = $movieBasic;
        $this->movieDetail = $movieDetail;

    }

    public function createMovie(array $attr) {

        // TODO: Move your business logic here.
        // E.g 
        $movie = $this->movieBasic->fill($attr); 
        $movie->save();
        return $movie;

    }

    public function createMovieDetail(array $movieAttr, array $attributes) {

        // TODO: Move your detail logic here.
        // E.g. 
        $basic = $this->createMovie($movieAttr);
        $detail = $this->movieDetail->fill($attributes);
        $detail->basic()->associate($detail);
        $detail->save();
        return $detail;

    }

}
```

And here, the controller examples:

```
<?php

use MovieService;

class MovieController {

    public function __construct(MovieService $ms) {
        $this->ms = $ms;
    }

    public function store() {
        $this->ms->createMovie($attrToSave);
    }

}

<?php

use MovieService;

class MovieDetailController {

    public function __construct(MovieService $ms) {
        $this->ms = $ms;
    }

    public function store() {
         $this->ms->createMovieDetail($attrToSave);
    }

}
```

Comment: from what I understand from your answer you abstracted out the create from both classes to a single class. Am I right in this? I think you missed another part my question. Do you have any idea as to what would be the best way to the same view? Ie both create functions go to 'cms.create' but present two different forms?

Comment: Nvm, will pass parameter to view and from that paramter determine which form to show